# how to notify the main thread using ThreadPool for parallel computation (PyQt)

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, pyqt

I have a for loop to read lots of image, and I want to use the multithread for acceleration. I can find many examples from Internet about QThread. However, many of those examples are not designed for acceleration.

Finally, I find an example that using multithread method to accelerate for loop. And the code is:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as DummyPool
from multiprocessing import Pool as ProcessPool
import time


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("QDicomLabel Test")
        self.resize(500, 500)

        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        btn = QPushButton('run')
        layout.addWidget(btn)

        label = QLabel('0')
        layout.addWidget(label)
        self.label = label
        btn.clicked.connect(self.run)

        self.num = 0

        self.finished.connect(self.updateText)

    def run(self):

        num = 4
        p = ThreadPool(num)
        start_time = time.time()
        ret = p.map(self.readfile, range(200))
        p.close()
        p.join()
        print("thread_pool  %d, costTime: %fs ret.size: %d" % (num, (time.time() - start_time), len(ret)))

    def readfile(self, name):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        # self.signal.finished.emit()

    def updateText(self):
        self.num = self.num + 1
        self.label.setText(str(self.num))
        # QCoreApplication.processEvents()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

In the above code, I need to read 200 image, and I assume that it will cost 0.01s to read each file. So, We need about 2s to read all files.

In run function, the variable 'num' affect the speed. If the num = 4, it will cost about 0.5s to read all files. Definitely, it accelerate my reading.

Then, I need to update the progress in the GUI. In my thought, I will emit a signal in the function 'readfile', and the function 'updateText' will receive the signal, then update the progress in GUI. The signal emitting has been annotated (self.signal.finished.emit()) in the function 'readfile', because it will crush the GUI.

So, how to update the progress in the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
def readfile(self, name):
    #time.sleep(0.01)
    QThread.msleep(10)
    # self.signal.finished.emit()
    self.finished.emit()
```

Comment: It don't work. The text update only when reading 200 files finished